# Converting Uint64 to 5 bytes and vice versa in c#

Tags: c#, type-conversion, byte, uint64

I have an application that expects 5 bytes that is derived of a number. Right now I am using Uint32 which is 4 bytes. I been told to make a class that uses a byte and a Uint32. However, im not sure how to combine them since they are numbers.

I figured the best way may be to use a Uint64 and convert it down to 5 bytes. However, I am not sure how that can be done. I need to be able to convert it to 5 bytes and a separate function in the class to convert it back to a Uint64.

Does anyone have any ideas on the best way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Where do you need to store that 5-byte int?

Comment: "Expects 5 bytes" -- how? where?

Comment: would this help you I am not sure..but it looks like it might http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.touint64.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Use [BitConverter.GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8z32tce.aspx) and then just remove the three bytes you don't need.

To convert it back use [BitConverter.ToUInt64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.touint64.aspx) remembering that you'll have to first pad your byte array with three extra (zero) bytes.

Just watch out for endianness. You may need to reverse your array if the application you are sending these bytes to expects the opposite endianess. Also the endianess will dictate whether you need to add/remove bytes from the start or end of the array. (check [BitConverter.IsLittleEndian](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.islittleendian.aspx))